# Search stored procedure returns cut off column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that searches all the tables in the database and returns the table that has the searched value.

My problem is that the value that I am searching is the value inside the XML that in the content of one of the table column.

When this stored procedure return the XML, the XML is cut off it is till middle of XML. How I can make changes to the stored procedure to return all the XML from that column.

This is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SearchAllTables]
   (@SearchStr nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Results TABLE(ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(max))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       SET @ColumnName = ''
       SET @TableName = (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                         WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                           AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                           AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
)

       WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
       BEGIN
          SET @ColumnName = (SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                               AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                               AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                               AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)

          IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO @Results
               EXEC ('SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                      FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                     ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2)
          END
      END 
  END

  SELECT * FROM @Results
END
```

Comment: instead of `nvarchar(100)` use `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Are you sure your MS SQL IDE isn't set to truncate the data? Go to Tools->Options->Query Results->SQL Server->Results to Grid and verify the "Maximum Characters Retrieved" setting.

Comment: Please tell me this is not your actual search algorithm you use every day. I have seen (and written) a number of search all columns in all tables pieces of code. There is one thing they all have in common. They are horribly slow and will cripple your database. If you are using this in production you might as well take your database out back and shoot it.

Comment: @Sean Lange, you are right it is too slow, I am using this in production data, is it bad practice??? please let me know if you have any nicer search algorithm, I need to search some part of XML data in table and the table is sooo big.

Comment: @Ash8087, I did what you said and put in on unlimited, but still it is truncate XML data.

Comment: Why are you only bringing back the first 3630 characters of the column value?

Comment: Well 2 things. What you are doing is searching every single column in every single table. There is not optimization that will help here. Next, you state you are searching XML but your datatypes you are looking through are not XML. Why not use the proper datatype? XML in this case. Why do you not know what table to look in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a search technique that actually gives the Query with which you can those column,
this is how I do, Hope it helps

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_SearchDBForValue 
    @search_string  VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SearchResultTableColumn')
    CREATE TABLE SearchResultTableColumn (SearchStr VARCHAR(101), RecCount SMALLINT, TableName VARCHAR(100), ColumnName VARCHAR(100), CreateDate DATETIME Default GETDATE())
ELSE
    DELETE FROM SearchResultTableColumn 

DECLARE 
@table_name     SYSNAME, 
@table_id       INT,
@column_name    SYSNAME,
@sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name, object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = @table_id AND system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239, 35)

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @table_name <> 'SearchResultTableColumn' 
        BEGIN
          SET @sql_string = 'DECLARE @RecCount SMALLINT '+
              'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @column_name + ' LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') '+
                'BEGIN SELECT @RecCount = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @column_name + ' LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'' '+
                'INSERT INTO SearchResultTableColumn VALUES( '''+@search_string+''', @RecCount,''' + @table_name + ''', ''' + @column_name + ''',GETDATE()) END '

            EXECUTE(@sql_string)
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    END

    CLOSE columns_cur

    DEALLOCATE columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id
END

CLOSE tables_cur

DEALLOCATE tables_cur
END;
GO

DECLARE @SearchStr VARCHAR (400)
BEGIN
 SET @SearchStr = 'A1000'
 EXECUTE SP_SearchDBForValue @SearchStr
 SELECT RecCount, 'SELECT '+ColumnName+' ColName, * FROM '+TableName+ ' WHERE  '+ColumnName+' LIKE ''%' +SearchStr+ '%''' FROM SearchResultTableColumn
END
GO
```